# PHP string goes empty unless echoed

Tags: php, string

I have the following test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo "Starting\n";

# Now read the file.
#
$file_pn = "contact.txt";
$fh = fopen($file_pn, 'r');
while (!feof($fh)) {
   $line = fgets($fh);
   $trimmed = trim($line);
   echo "trimmed = <" . $trimmed . ">\n";
   if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $trimmed)) {
      echo "Looks blank: trimmed = <" . $trimmed . ">\n";
      #continue;
   }
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

The file being read has some blank lines and some non-blank lines. As shown here, it acts as one would expect: only the lines that are actually blank receive the "Looks blank" message, and trimmed = <>. But if I comment out the echo statement in line 12 and run the script again, $trimmed always appears to be the empty string when we get to the if statement. It is as if $trimmed gets clobbered unless it has been echoed. How can this be?

Comment: You're opening the file.. You won't see the result if you don't use echo.. That's what I understand in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to be using a regex there.  If the line is only whitespace to begin with, `trim()` will make it empty.

Try:

```
if (empty($trimmed)) {
```

It behaves as expected for me - since you're now not echoing any lines that aren't empty, your output will only show a heap of empty lines

```
$ ./test|wc -l
18
$ nano test #comment line 12
$ ./test|wc -l
6
```

Comment: I agree that I do not need the regex, but whether or not it is empty should be the same whether it was echoed or not. Changing the test as suggested still shows exactly the same bizarre behavior.

Comment: calcinai, you are right. I saw the "heap of empty lines" and mistakenly thought that there were as many of them as total lines in the file. But there were only as many as actual empty lines. So it was my own reasoning that was bizarre.